# $p$-adic integers form integral doamain

Tags: solution-verification

I am trying to prove that the ring of $p$-adic integers contains no zero-divisors.

Let $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ be $p$-adic integers (so $a_i\in\mathbb{Z}/p^i$ and  $a_{n+1}\equiv a_n \pmod{p^n}$ and same for $b$'s).

If these numbers are non-zero, let $a_s$ be the first term in $(a_n)$ which is not $0$ and $b_r$ be the first term in $(b_n)$ which is non-zero.

We can assume that $s\ge r$.

Since $(a_n)(b_n)=0$, so $a_{2s}b_{2s}\equiv 0\pmod{p^{2s}}$.

So $p^s$ should divide $a_{2s}$ or $b_{2s}$.

- If $p^s$ divides $a_{2s}$ then it also divides $a_s$, i.e. $a_s=0$, contradiction.
- If $p^s$ divides $b_{2s}$ then it also divides $b_s$, hence to $b_r$, i.e. $b_r=0$, a  contradiction.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you prove that $\Bbb{Z}_p$ is an integral domain?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/615102/how-do-you-prove-that-bbbz-p-is-an-integral-domain) You can compare it, and see new ideas, too.

Comment: I am asking whether my *proof is correct*? I put the tag of proof-verification (I am beginner in this with self-study)

Comment: Others have done this proof, too. Why don't you compare it? Perhaps it is easier to use one of the shorter ideas for proof? I understand, that one wants to find flaws, but here a new proof seems better. For the solution tag, you need to explain exactly where you have doubts.